# Wheels for fat guy - 27.5" vs 29"

Tags: mountain-bike, 29er, heavy, 27-inch

As a 140kg, 1.8m tall (79.5cm inseam),  I will be mostly riding roads until I lose some weight, but I was thinking which wheels do you think would be better given my situation, given I want a mountain bike? Would the 29" be better since I will be mostly ride roads (at least at the start, until I lose weight and maybe try some off-road)?

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is.  If you bought a 29" bike don't go spending more money to change the wheel size before even getting some experience with what you have!  At 140kg you probably want to look into getting a stronger high-spoke-count wheel regardless of wheel size.  Otherwise it's pretty much personal preference and we can't tell you which you prefer...

Comment: My bad, I removed the ambiguity, hopefully. Indeed, the size was the question, I did not intend to change the wheel on the 29er I got, but I was thinking if I should return it and swap it for a 27.5er. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

In theory, a smaller wheel is stronger than a bigger wheel if hub and rim section are the same.

This is largely due to the length of the spoke and it's contributions to the stiffness/flex vs spoke braking force.

Whether the difference between a 27.5 wheel and a 29 wheel is in of itself enough to mean a real world differe, I don't think so.

I think a strongly made (ie specially made for heavier rider) 29er wheel, will be stronger than a generic OEM (for the masses) 27.5 wheel.

I would strongly suggest you pick the bike you will enjoy riding more, and replace the wheels with a stronger wheelset when you need to.

This is exactly what my friend (125kg) did, he bought a bike, and I built him a stronger rear wheel with a Hope Pro 4 hub, DT Swiss eBike specific spokes (brass nipples) and a downhill rim. It was heavy, it will outlast his bike frame...